# Transform a golang map into another structure of map

Tags: go, slice, go-map

I need help for transforming this input map into the output map. I try with switch/case and for but I didn't succeed it. Thanks a lot  !

**Input :**

```
Values{
                    "toto_voiture_brand": Ad{
                        "CITROEN": "CITROEN",
                    },
                    "toto_voiture_model": Ad{
                        "CITROEN_toto": "C3",
                    },
                    "toto_moto_brand": Ad{
                        "KAWASAKI": "KAWASAKI",
                    },
                    "toto_moto_model": Ad{
                        "KAWASAKI_tata": "Ninja 1000 SX",
                    },
                    "toto_camion_brand": Ad{
                        "RENAULT": "RENAULT",
                        "PEUGEOT": "PEUGEOT",
                    },
                    "toto_camion_model": Ad{
                        "RENAULT_toto":  "J5",
                        "PEUGEOT_tata": "255",
                    },
                },
            }
```

**Output**

```
Values{
                "toto_voiture_model": {
                    "Citroen": {
                        {Value: "C3"},
                    },
                },
                "toto_moto_model": {
                    "Kawasaki": {
                        {Value: "Ninja 1000 SX"},
                    },
                },
                "toto_camion_model": {
                    "RENAULT": {
                        {Value: "J5"},
                    },
                    "PEUGEOT": {
                        {Value: "255"},
                    },
                },
            }
```

I've tried with switch case and loop for and map. But I don't have the result attendee, I didn't found how to match every map, key and value. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have managed what you need with the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Output struct {
    Value string `json:"Value"`
}

func main() {
    // declare output
    output := make(map[string]map[string]Output, 0)
    // input
    input := make(map[string]map[string]string, 0)
    input["toto_voiture_brand"] = map[string]string{
        "CITROEN": "CITROEN",
    }
    input["toto_voiture_model"] = map[string]string{
        "CITROEN_toto": "C3",
    }
    input["toto_moto_model"] = map[string]string{
        "KAWASAKI_tata": "Ninja 1000 SX",
    }
    input["toto_camion_model"] = map[string]string{
        "RENAULT_toto": "J5",
        "PEUGEOT_tata": "255",
    }

    // transformation
    for k, v := range input {
        if strings.HasSuffix(k, "_model") {
            tempMap := make(map[string]Output, len(v))
            for kk, vv := range v {
                key := strings.Split(kk, "_")[0]
                tempMap[key] = Output{
                    Value: vv,
                }
            }
            output[k] = tempMap
        }
    }

    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(&output, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

I put some comments within the code just to separate sections. The first two parts are only supposed to define your input and output variables.
The section starting with `// transformation` is a good candidate to become a function but I preferred to leave it within the `main` function for demo purposes. Let me recap what's happens in the `loop`:

1. You range over the entries of your `input` variable
2. If the key has the suffix `_model`, you take it into consideration
3. You define a locally-scoped map (called `tempMap`) of type `map[string]Output` with the right number of elements that we're gonna add
4. You range over the `v` variable (that's why we're dealing with nested maps)
5. For each item, you're gonna add an entry to the `tempMap`
6. At the end of the nested loop, you add an entry to the parent map (`output`)

The last part is only for printing a beautiful JSON that can be easily read and checked.

> Note that this code is simplified just to show off how to achieve your goal, adjust it before putting it into production.

Let me know if this helps, thanks!